# Can git or mercurial do scatter/gather?

Tags: git, windows-7, mercurial

I've got important configuration files in different places on my Windows 7 PC. I'd like to keep these in version control and replicate them to my other PCs.

Can I use git or mercurial to keep them all in one repository, even though they're in a variety of places on my PC?

If this was a Linux box, I'd put them all in a single folder and use symlinks. Since this is Windows, that's not really possible.

So: can I configure (somehow) git or mercurial to "gather" the files together when committing or pushing, and to "scatter" the files to the correct destinations when pulling or updating?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use symbolic links also:

```
C:>mklink /?
Creates a symbolic link.

MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

    /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
            symbolic link.
    /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
    /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
    Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
    Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
            refers to.
```

Comment: I don't particularly trust symlinks on Windows, since most applications don't know anything about them.

Comment: Well, the point is that they rarely need to (unlike Windows shortcuts). Alteratively, you can make hardlinks (for files, but must be on same volume) or junctions (for directories) - these also don't require privilege elevation (creating a symlink normally does). The one major issue with symlinks is that you can't follow them through CIFS shares, whereas hardlinks and junctions work fine. I recommend installing the Link Shell Extension: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html.

Answer (score 0):

Consider separating deployment from version control. You might find that this gives you more options if the files you have under version control must be processed before the can be used (like copied to their final places).

No, none of the two can do the deployment for you.

You can use the post-receive hook (if you can get it running on Windows) in Git to automatically copy the files from the commits you pushed to deployment systems, though.

Comment: The problem is: once I've edited the files in their home location (and this is a requirement), they need to be copied back to the working copy before they can be committed. This defeats the point.

Comment: Maybe use a script which gathers the files in the repository?